# When editing a Word document on a WebDAV server, where is the file written to locally?

Tags: cpu-word, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I know that when you edit a WebDAV document the file is downloaded from the server, and changes are synchronized, but surely the file is written to the local drive somewhere - does anyone know where?

Or does the file truly only exist in memory and on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by installing "Everything" search and editing a WebDAV document. I saw this file pop up every time I made an edit, so it looks like Word is writing the changes to a temporary file with a GUID name in the local app data temp folder.

[image]